# GitHub Pages не прогружают стили по BEM методологии

Tags: css, бэм, github-pages

Пишу простой проектик, дабы потренироваться в BEM методологии, хотел залить его на GH Pages, но мои стили не находит.

Стили я подключал в корнях проекта, в папке pages/index.css в таком виде:

```
@import url(./../vendor/normalize.css);
@import url(./../vendor/fonts/fonts.css);

@import url(./../blocks/background/background.css);

@import url(./../blocks/card/card.css);

@import url(./../blocks/first-section/first-section.css);
@import url(./../blocks/first-section/__form/first-section__form.css);
@import url(./../blocks/first-section/__input/first-section__input.css);
@import url(./../blocks/first-section/__label/first-section__label.css);
@import url(./../blocks/first-section/__error/first-section__error.css);

@import url(./../blocks/second-section/second-section.css);
@import url(./../blocks/second-section/__line/second-section__line.css);
@import url(./../blocks/second-section/__btn/second-section__btn.css);

@import url(./../blocks/third-section/third-section.css);
@import url(./../blocks/third-section/__text/third-section__text.css);
@import url(./../blocks/third-section/__span/third-section__span.css);
@import url(./../blocks/third-section/__title/third-section__title.css);
```

Следственно, стили у меня храняться в корне проекта, в папке blocks и т.д...
На Live Server и просто через index.html стили работают корректно, но при попытке залить проект на GH Pages у меня в консоли полно ошибок 404 "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()".

Пытался указать относительные, и абсолютные пути, проблема всё таже.

Comment: Вы смотрели откуда в итоге идет попытка получить файл?

Answer (score 1):

Если верить данной [ветке на GH](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22495#discussioncomment-3237025), должно работать, но вместо одной точки попробуйте две, если, конечно же, ваш html углублён на два уровня

```
@import url(../../vendor/normalize.css);
```

---

Попробуйте как [здесь](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/22495#discussioncomment-3237030) указано через link:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/vendor/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/normalize.css">
```

С слэшем вначале и без него. Опять же, если как вы говорите в комментариях, index лежит в root.

Comment: Не, у меня есть папка проекта, в котором index.html, папка blocks, и папка pages. Внутри папки pages файл index.css куда я импоритую все свои стили, а в папке blocks по папкам уже разбросаны стили.
Проблема в том, что оно у меня везде работает, кроме GH pages

Comment: @GontieFox если index в root лежит, то на уровень выше через точки нет необходимости ходить.

Comment: Понимаю. Я что ещё заметил только щас, у меня стили для некоторых элементов работают. Из импортов, background и card отображает правильно, а вот остальные импорты, где уже элементы есть, оно их не отображает

Comment: @GontieFox, `везде работает кроме GH` говорить "везде" когда это самое "везде" состоит из пары пунктов... не громковато ли?) (index.html явно с иными путями к файлам нежели в css, и live server...) за LS ничего сказать не могу, но как минимум тут на stack overflow в сниппете точно есть что то вроде авто коррекции банальных ошибок, как раз вроде такой точки в путях. словом, поправьте наконец пути и увидим в них ли дело. удалить по паре символов из десятка путей, это ж не ОС с нуля написать...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать файл .nojekyll в корне проекта. Генератор сайтов в гитхаб пейджес не поддерживает БЭМ